# Dynamic programming

Tags: algorithm, visual-c++, dynamic-programming

I was given a task of making all possible combinations of a 2d array through brute force algorithm and then find the best from all of them through its cost.

For example, if the array is of size 4 X 3, and it has contents let's say:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
10 11 12
```

then one of possible combination can be

```
1
4
7
10
```

similarly

```
1
4
7
11
```

...

```
1
4
7
12
```

...

```
1
4
8
10
```

...

```
1
4
8
11
```

...

and so on, hence all such combinations. Remember the above mentioned combinations were stored in a 2d array, and " - " was inserted where there was no number. For example:

```
1 - -
4 - -
7 - -
10 - -
```

but as it's a 2d array, you can't store ' - ' in it, so it will only be displayed like it. Now, there will be a randomly generated cost to every combination. As in brute force, first I find all combinations and then select best combination of it. It took lot of time, for example if my array is 10 X 5.

Then I have to make 5^10 combinations, which is a huge amount, and time consuming. I actually want someone to help me making alternative of it through dynamic programing. The array can be of size n x m, where m can be 2 or 3 maximum and n can be of maximum 1000. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is a valid "combination" in a 2d array?

Comment: 1 - -, 4 - -,7 - -,10 - -, is valid and all like it i mentioned above are examples of valid combinations

Comment: You say it's a 2d array, but all the number sequences you've written are one-dimensional. Can you double-check the formatting of your question? (hint: put four spaces in front of a line for block formatting)

Comment: 1 - -                                                                 4 - -                                                                        7 - -                                                                       10 - -                                                                             now this is a possible combination...note that as the array was of size m x n...so that we can select m numbers at a time to make combinations....and note that no number of a row or column should repeat

Comment: what do those slashes represent? Could you edit your original post to be more clear?

Comment: it means new line...plz suppose that u have a 2d array in the table format...i don't know how to represent it there...hope u understand

Comment: You say that no number of a row or column should repeat. But 1 and 4 are in the same column. Does that mean [1,4,7,10] is not a valid sequence?

Comment: it means that no number of a row or column should repeat in a combination...for e.g.  1 - -/4 - - /7 - 4/10 - -.....now u can see that 4 was in 1st column 2nd row ...but it was repeated in 3rd row...so its not a valid combination....

Comment: Are you allowed to have two numbers in one row? For example, in your last comment you had `7-4`.

Comment: no it will be invalid....u can have a combination like....           - 2 -/
- 5 -/
7 - -/
- 11 -/

Comment: what is the best combination? the maximum sum?

Comment: yes .................................

Comment: i think it can be done like matrix chain multiplicayion in DP

Answer (score 1):

Is 1 - - / - - 6 / - - 9 / - - 12 valid? I think the problem you may be asking is what is the cheapest path through this matrix, which is a standard Dynamic Programming Problem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#Checkerboard.

Otherwise if the problem means simply max sum, then just do max in each row, which should be clear, since you can only have one element per row.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive (Brute force solution) to this problem can be as below:

```
private static void combinations(int[][] matrix, int output[],int row, int col,int index,int n) {

    // base case
    if(row==n)
    {
        printArray(output,row);
        return;
    }

    for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
    {
        output[index] = matrix[row][j];
        combinations(matrix,output, row+1, col,index+1,n);
    }
    return;
}

private static void printArray(int[] output, int row) {
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        System.out.print(output[i]+ ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

In this, the function combinations is called for number of columns times. For each combination of columns, output array is printed. I am not very sure about optimization for this problem. If someone knows more optimized algorithm, please share.